# how to load unique rows into data warehouse from database using tmysql rows in talend

Tags: database, ssis, data-warehouse, talend

sample input data:

```
city    state  country 
boston   MA    US
chennai  TN    India 
boston   MA    US
```

output i need to load in data warehouse:

```
city    state  country 
boston   MA    US
chennai  TN    India
```

i don't want to use tunite or tuniquerow component in talend.

Answer (score 0):

If you are loading from MySQL with a custom `SELECT` statement you could use the `DISTINCT` keyword to get only one instance of each row combination.

E.g.:

```
SELECT DISTINCT city, state, country FROM mytable
```